# Can I download the iOS framework before compiling the resources?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I have an iOS application that uses a third party library. They are not stored on the same repository.

I have made a Python script that downloads the library from the remote repository but this needs to happen before the application compiles the source files.

I have tried with "Run Script Phase" before "Compile Sources" and even as "Pre Build Action" but none of this worked.

Is there any other way I can make this work ?
[thank you]

Comment: which third party library you are using? Also Are you using cocoapods / carthage?

Comment: This may be unnecessary. That's why Carthage/Cocopods dependancy mangers don't download frameworks on each build. I see this will be useful only if library changes every min/hour!!!. Even after that, I think build time will be so high. I recommend you should stay away from this unless absolutely needed.